# Is there an optimal way to apply a string to a variable other than an if/else chain

Tags: php

I am pulling a variable string `Rarity` from an API.

I then need to shorten this string depending on what I receive. So I am using a big if/else block:

```
if($rarity == "Common"){
    $rarestring = "(C)";
}else if($rarity == "Rare"){
    $rarestring = "(R)";
}else if($rarity == "Super Rare"){
    $rarestring = "(SR)";
}else if($rarity == "Holofoil Rare"){
    $rarestring = "(HFR)";
}else if($rarity == "Ultra Rare"){
    $rarestring = "(UR)";
}else if($rarity == "Ultimate Rare"){
    $rarestring = "(UtR)";
}else if($rarity == "Secret Rare"){
    $rarestring = "(ScR)";
}else if($rarity == "Ultra Secret Rare"){
    $rarestring = "(UScR)";
}else if($rarity == "Secret Ultra Rare"){
    $rarestring = "(SCuR)";
}else if($rarity == "Prismatic Secret Rare"){
    $rarestring = "(PScR)";
}else if($rarity == "Ghost Rare"){
    $rarestring = "(GR)";
}else if($rarity == "Parallel Rare"){
    $rarestring = "(PR)";
}else if($rarity == "Parallel Common"){
    $rarestring = "(PC)";
}else if($rarity == "Super Parallel Rare"){
    $rarestring = "(SPR)";
}else if($rarity == "Ultra Parallel Rare "){
    $rarestring = "(UPR)";
}else if($rarity == "Duel Terminal Parallel Common"){
    $rarestring = "(DPC)";
}else if($rarity == "Duel Terminal Rare Parallel Rare"){
    $rarestring = "(DRPR)";
}else if($rarity == "Duel Terminal Super Parallel Rare"){
    $rarestring = "(DSPR)";
}else if($rarity == "Duel Terminal Ultra Parallel Rare"){
    $rarestring = "(DUPR)";
}else if($rarity == "Duel Terminal Secret Parallel Rare"){
    $rarestring = "(DScPR)";
}else if($rarity == "Gold Rare"){
    $rarestring = "(GUR)";
}
```

I can't help but feel that this isn't optimal. I know if/else aren't usually that performance intensive but I feel like this might be a good opportunity to learn something and potentially do it better.

I figured I could put all the rarities into an array but I still came out with the same issue where I need to compare it and then shorten.

Comment: array mapping is one possible approach e.g. `$array = ["Common"=>"C", ...]` ... then `return $array[$rarity]`

Comment: `$rarity_map=array('Common' => '(C)', 'Rare' => '(R)');` Then you can check if given array key exists and return it like so: $rarity_map['Common']. You can also parse it from db to make it more dynamic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, use array mapping:

```
$options = [
  'Common' => '(C)',
  'Rare' => '(R)',
];
//...
if (!isset($options[$rarity])) {
  throw new Exception('Unknown rarity ' . $rarity);
}
$rarestring = $options[$rarity];
```

Or you can use the switch construct:

```
switch($rarity) {
  case 'Common': $rarestring = '(C)'; break;
  case 'Rare': $rarestring = '(R)'; break;
  default: throw new Exception('Unknown rarity ' . $rarity);
}
```

EDIT:

For those who may read this is future.
As opposed to what many would say, that array is always better, there is a real difference between those two approaches (array vs switch), other that the way it is written in code.

Switch behaves very much like sequence of elseifs - it allows to execute block of a code per each case and the last case takes the most time to get to, because all previous cases must have been compared to the needle ($rarity in case above). Time complexity O(n). Memory complexity O(1).

On other hand, array allows only the use case when each case should give back a predefined value. And in PHP array is implemented as hash table with time complxity of the key lookup t being O(1) < t < O(n). And memory complexity being O(n).

Comment: " but when it comes to huge set of options, arrays might not be the best choice." - Perhaps you need to edit this line

Comment: well its true that the switch neither :D

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this,

```
$arr = [
    "Common"                             => "(C)",
    "Rare"                               => "(R)",
    "Super Rare"                         => "(SR)",
    "Holofoil Rare"                      => "(HFR)",
    "Ultra Rare"                         => "(UR)",
    "Ultimate Rare"                      => "(UtR)",
    "Secret Rare"                        => "(ScR)",
    "Ultra Secret Rare"                  => "(UScR)",
    "Secret Ultra Rare"                  => "(SCuR)",
    "Prismatic Secret Rare"              => "(PScR)",
    "Ghost Rare"                         => "(GR)",
    "Parallel Rare"                      => "(PR)",
    "Parallel Common"                    => "(PC)",
    "Super Parallel Rare"                => "(SPR)",
    "Ultra Parallel Rare "               => "(UPR)",
    "Duel Terminal Parallel Common"      => "(DPC)",
    "Duel Terminal Rare Parallel Rare"   => "(DRPR)",
    "Duel Terminal Super Parallel Rare"  => "(DSPR)",
    "Duel Terminal Ultra Parallel Rare"  => "(DUPR)",
    "Duel Terminal Secret Parallel Rare" => "(DScPR)",
    "Gold Rare"                          => "(GUR)",
];
echo ($arr[$rarity] ?? 'nothing');
```

You don't need to write any switch or if-else blocks for this.